# Removing record from view on a Ajax.ActionLink C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I have a piece of code that i thought worked at one time. I may have it wrong and cannot find anything like it through my search. The below code deletes the record but does not remove the record from the view without refreshing the page. Can anyone see what might be wrong with this?

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.VendorId },
       new AjaxOptions()
       {
          HttpMethod="Delete",
          Confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this " + item.VendorName,
          OnComplete = "function() { $(this).parent().parent().remove }"
       }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })
```

I am using DataTables if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks for your help!

So what i ended up doing, not sure if it is right or not. I took the line out of OnComplete added Delete to the class and created another function. It works, but not sure if it is overkill or not..

```
$(document).on('click', '.Delete', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: You are relying on a DOM structure where what you want to remove is 2 levels up. You could debug that in Chrome tools, but I would use a more flexible selector that references a <tr> or class. For example `$(this).closest('<tr>').remove()`

Comment: I added what i did. Not sure if it is the best solution or not though..

Comment: Your first remove does not have trailing parens. The way you have it now it will be removed even if person answers NO to confirm.

Comment: So it should be: $(this).parent().parent().remove()""; Or am i not understanding correctly?

Comment: Sorry maybe like this $(this).parent().parent().remove();""

Comment: Yes, make your 1st `remove` like the 2nd one(working). You should see console errors when javascript fails.